# How to show alert dialog in flutter when app is closed?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I am working on a task application in flutter. Where I want to implement a functionality that is when i create a task i want to set time for that and after particular time i want to show a alert box even if the app is closed. how can I do this ?

I have integrated the firebase so I can get notificatios even if the app is closed but how to show dialog box in flutter ?

Comment: `Service`/`ForegroundService`, `WindowManager`, Inflate the `View` & add it to the window via relevant `LayoutParams`. This would require systems overlay permission as well.

Comment: On iOS you will need to post a local notification

Comment: @Darshan sir, Can you provide me some code snippet or a blog article link or something ?